# Are Ruby class methods thread-safe?

Tags: ruby, methods, thread-safety

For instance, methods such as:

```
class MyClass
  self.perform(id)
    hash = doSomething(id)
    doMoreStuff(hash)
    return hash
  end
end
```

My concern is if I have multiple threads calling `MyClass.perform()`. Could the object `hash` be potentially overwritten by another thread? In other words, Thread 1 calls `doSomething` and gets a hash returned of `{1 => 1}`. But right afterwards Thread 2 calls `doSomething` and gets a hash of `{2 => 2}`. What happens now? Does Thread 1's hash change to `{2 => 2}`?

Or does each thread work on its own `hash` that can never be touched by other threads? Assume `doSomething` and `doMoreStuff` are already thread-safe.

If it matters, I am using Rails 3.0.

Comment: As far as I know, with rails, for example, they aren't

Comment: Can you explain what thread-safety concerns you have about the method?

Comment: Also, there's no need for `return` at the end of the method. If you just have `hash` on the last line, that'll be the return value.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwritten"?

Comment: Just to confirm, the `{1 => 1}` hash object is a different object than the `{2 => 2}`, hash object, right? It's not that the first object has had its state modified, is it?

Comment: Local variables are local to the method call so there's nothing to worry about if `hash` really is a local variable. OTOH, if it is really `@hash`, `@@hash`, `$hash`, or something else that isn't local then you can have problems.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks, that was what I needed to know. If you could put in the answers, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The local variables, such as your `hash`, are local to the particular invocation of the surrounding method. If two threads end up calling `perform` at the same time, then each call will get its own execution context and those won't overlap unless there are shared resources involved: instance variables (`@hash`), class variables (`@@hash`), globals (`$hash`), ... can cause concurrency problems. There's nothing to worry about thread-wise with something simple like your `perform`.

However, if `perform` was creating threads and you ended up with closures inside `perform`, then you could end up with several threads referencing the same local variables captured through the closures. So you do have to be careful about scope issues when you create threads but you don't have to worry about it when dealing with simple methods that only work with local variables.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer. Can you provide an example of "if perform was creating threads and you ended up with closures inside perform"?

Comment: @BSeven Hard to come up with an example seven years later but if you have `x = 0; f = ->{ x += 1 }; g = ->{ x += 3 }` then you have two closures (`f` and `g`) that are sharing state in a variable (`x`) that is local to the surrounding method. If the method is creating its own threads then local variables can end up being shared amongst those threads (but still not shared between threads or lambdas across different calls to `perform`). Highly contrived examples of course. The call itself is safe but the method can do unsafe things.

Answer (score 3):

Something being a "class method" (which is just a singleton method on a class object) doesn't make it any more thread-safe than it being an instance method.

Comment: @Downvoter when the answer was written, the question was really vague, and I couldn't provide much more information than this. I'm still trying to clarify what the OP is asking, so please don't downvote this answer.